# How to inject a class with constructor parameter in MVC?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

Apologies if this has been answered.  I've searched and cannot find a solution for it.

How do you inject a class with a constructor parameter in MVC in #5?  And is it even possible?

For the codes below, it will have an error since it cannot construct MyHelper1 that was injected because it is missing the sqlContext parameter.

Here are my (simplified) objects:

```
// 1. HELPER CLASS TO INJECT
public class MyHelper1 : HelperBase, IHelper
{
    public MyHelper1(IHelperSqlContext sqlContext) : HelperBase(sqlContext)
    public override string HelperTag { get; } = "HELPER1";
    . . .
}

// 2. BASE HELPER
public abstract class HelperBase 
{
    private IHelperSqlContext _sqlContext;
    abstract public string HelperTag { get; }
    public HelperBase(IHelperSqlContext sqlContext)
    {
        _sqlContext = sqlContext;
    }
    public List<HelperRecords> GetRecords(Id id)
    {
        return _sqlContext.GetRecords(id);
    }
    . . . 
}

// 3. INTERFACE
public interface IHelper
{
    . . . 

}

// 4. CONTROLLER
public class MyController : Controller
{
    IHelper _myHelper
    public MyController(IHelper myHelper)
    {
         _myHelper = myHelper;
    }

    public IActionResult Index(Id id)
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        model.MyRecords = _myHelper.GetRecords(id);
        return View(model);
    }
}

// 5. STARTUP - INJECT PART
public class Startup
{
    . . .
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        . . . 
        // How to pass MyHelper1 class with IHelperSqlContext here???
        services.AddTransient<IHelper, MyHelper1>();
    }  
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start with the [official Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection). It is pretty good. If you have any specific questions afterwards, please post a new question here on SO.

Comment: Thanks @Steven.  I've read it and I think my problem is similar to that part =>        public CharacterRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) . . and in the ConfigureServices,  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>  options.UseInMemoryDatabase() );
 and this =>     services.AddScoped<ICharacterRepository, CharacterRepository>();  like what NKosi is suggesting below.
My problem is it is getting compilation error saying "IServiceCollection does not contain AddDbContext". Potential fixes shows "Add package MS EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.0. We are not using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you need to do is register all the dependencies (that means your dependencies dependencies as well) in the ConfigureServices method in the Startup class.

So in this case you need to add a line like this.

```cs
services.AddTransient<IHelperSqlContext, MyHelperSqlContext>();
```

You can get more information in the Microsoft docs for dependency injection [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection).

Comment: Thanks Roy.  I tried it and got an error something like "InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'MyNameSpace.MyHelperSqlContext'."  But this might be another issue (how to pass it correctly).  I'll read the link and try to figure it out, and if it works, then I'll make your post as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

All dependencies need to be registered with the DI container so that it knows how to resolve it and its dependencies.

The following assumes that the abstraction is implemented as a DbContext derived class.

```
public class Startup {
    //. . .

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

        //. . . 

        //Register your context with dependency injection
        services.AddDbContext<HelperSqlDbContext>(options =>    
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
        );
        //register the context with its abstraction
        service.AddScoped<IHelperSqlContext, HelperSqlDbContext>()

        services.AddTransient<IHelper, MyHelper1>();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Nkosi.  It is throwing me an error on the AddDbContext line => "Error CS1061 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddDbContext' and no extension method 'AddDbContext' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".  FYI.  We are not using EntityFramework.